# Tokenize a mathematical expression in Python

Tags: python, math

I tried to write a function to tokenize a mathematical expression, converting an input string into a list of tokens, but without success. Is there an easy way to do this in Python? For example, given the expression

sin( 1 + 2 * x ) + tan( 2.123 * x ),

I want to obtain the list

```
[ 'sin', '(', '1', '+', '2', '*', 'x', ')', '+', 'tan', '(', '2.123', '*', 'x', ')' ]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried anything, or were you hoping we'd write it for you?

Comment: Googling "write lexer in python" produces lots of relevant results. I'd recommend you explore those first.

Comment: Like I said, I did try.

Comment: I deleted the code, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Your parenthesis do not match or even exist

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `tokenize`-module. http://docs.python.org/2/library/tokenize.html Here is an example

```
>>> s = "sin( 1 + 2 * x ) + tan( 2.123 * x "
>>> import tokenize
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> tokenize.tokenize(StringIO(s).readline)
1,0-1,3:    NAME    'sin'
1,3-1,4:    OP  '('
1,5-1,6:    NUMBER  '1'
1,7-1,8:    OP  '+'
1,9-1,10:   NUMBER  '2'
1,11-1,12:  OP  '*'
1,13-1,14:  NAME    'x'
1,15-1,16:  OP  ')'
1,17-1,18:  OP  '+'
1,19-1,22:  NAME    'tan'
1,22-1,23:  OP  '('
1,24-1,29:  NUMBER  '2.123'
1,30-1,31:  OP  '*'
1,32-1,33:  NAME    'x'
# and now occurs some error you have to catch
```

And there is an other approach using regular expressions:

Here is the link for the explanation of the reg-ex and this site is also a great tool for testing/exploring regex: http://regex101.com/r/bP6kH1

```
>>> s = "sin( 1 + 2 * x ) + tan( 2.123 * x "
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r"(\b\w*[\.]?\w+\b|[\(\)\+\*\-\/])", s)
['sin', '(', '1', '+', '2', '*', 'x', ')', '+', 'tan', '(', '2.123', '*', 'x']
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com) to parse an expression of this type:

```
from pyparsing import *

expr = Forward()

double = Word(nums + ".").setParseAction(lambda t:float(t[0]))
integer = Word(nums).setParseAction(lambda t:int(t[0]))
variable = Word(alphas)
string = dblQuotedString
funccall = Group(variable + "(" + Group(Optional(delimitedList(expr))) + ")")
array_func = Group(funccall + "[" + Group(delimitedList(expr, "][")) + "]")
array_var = Group(variable + "[" + Group(delimitedList(expr, "][")) + "]")

operand = double | string | array_func | funccall | array_var | variable

expop = Literal('^')
signop = oneOf('+ -')
multop = oneOf('* /')
plusop = oneOf('+ -')

expr << operatorPrecedence( operand,
[("^", 2, opAssoc.RIGHT),
(signop, 1, opAssoc.RIGHT),
(multop, 2, opAssoc.LEFT),
(plusop, 2, opAssoc.LEFT),]
)

result = expr.parseString('sin( 1 + 2 * x ) + tan( 2.123 * x )')
print result
```

Prints:

```
[[['sin', '(', [[1.0, '+', [2.0, '*', 'x']]], ')'], '+', ['tan', '(', [[2.123, '*', 'x']], ')']]]
```

It is a nested list to allow operator precedence to be respected. To get the flat list you wanted, just flatten the list:

```
import collections

def flatten(l):
    for el in l:
        if isinstance(el, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(el, basestring):
            for sub in flatten(el):
                yield sub
        else:
            yield el

print list(flatten(result))
```

Prints:

```
['sin', '(', 1.0, '+', 2.0, '*', 'x', ')', '+', 'tan', '(', 2.123, '*', 'x', ')']
```

Or, if you just want to tokenize without any respect to operator precedence or structure, you can do that in one line:

```
>>> from pyparsing import *
>>> OneOrMore(Word(alphas+"_", alphanums+"_") | Word(printables)).parseString("sin( 1 + 2 * x ) + tan( 2.123 * x )").asList()
['sin', '(', '1', '+', '2', '*', 'x', ')', '+', 'tan', '(', '2.123', '*', 'x', ')']
```