# Regular Expression for Mathematical Expression Python

Tags: python, regex

I would like to come out with a regax which is able to match the mathematical expression which is being stored in `exp`.

The pattern of the expression starts and end with bracket and cannot contain any letters. The expression may contain integers or floats, and the operators can be `+-*/**`. Length of the expression is not limited.

This is my regex:

```
import re
re.match(r'^[(]([(-]?([0-9]+)[)]??)([(]?([-+/*]([0-9]))?([.]?[0-9]+)?[)])[)]*$', exp)
```

However my regex doesn't match with some of the strings.
For example:

- `exp = '(( 200 + (4 * 3.14)) / ( 2 ** 3 ))'`
- `exp = '(23.23+23)'`
- `exp = '((23**2)/23)'`
- `exp = '(23.34-(3*2))'`

I am new to regular expression and I am not sure which part of the expression is wrong, please forgive me for the trouble and hope that someone can help me with it.
Thank you so much!

Comment: Regex are in general not good at parsing expressions because of problems with nested brackets. Please edit your code into your question as a [mre] - anyone should be able to paste it into a file and _without adding anything_ run it to see the same problem you see. That means you need to include imports and some minimal data (maybe the expressions you show, as initializations in Python code) that shows the problem you’re having.

Comment: Totally agree with @barny, regex should not be used for complex parsing. You should build a parser for that. Use the right tool for the job!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tokenize a mathematical expression in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20805614/tokenize-a-mathematical-expression-in-python)

Comment: As the others have stated, this is not an appropriate use of regex. You need to parse it properly. Luckily this has been done before and there are tools out there that can do the job, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20805614/tokenize-a-mathematical-expression-in-python).

Comment: The `ast` module contains this functionality (and more), at least for expressions which are also valid Python expressions (which seems to be the case here). Using `ast` doesn't just get you the tokens, but gets you a parse tree that allows you to evaluate the expression.

Comment: @barny yes thank you for the suggestion! I have edited my codes, questions and my problem above. Sorry for the trouble and thank you so much!

Comment: @costaparas yep I am able to tokenize the expression, however the expression doesn't match the regex. Should be something wrong with the regex

Answer (score 1):

You could approach it as "splitting" the string with operators being your separators.  This would save you from trying to represent numbers in your regular expression.

So you only need an expression that will pick up the 5 operators and parentheses.  This can be expressed using a pipe between operators with the longest operator (**) being first.

```
import re
symbols   = ["**","+","-","*","/","(",")"]    # longest first
tokens    = re.compile("("+"|".join(map(re.escape,symbols))+")")
            # placing symbols in a group makes re.split keep the separators

def tokenize(exp):
  parts = map(str.strip,tokens.split(exp)) # split and strip spaces
  return list(filter(None,parts))          # remove empty parts

exp = '(( 200 + (4 * 3.14)) / ( 2 ** 3 ))'
print(tokenize(exp))
['(', '(', '200', '+', '(', '4', '*', '3.14', ')', ')', '/', '(', '2', '**', '3', ')', ')']


exp = '(23.23+23)'
print(tokenize(exp))
['(', '23.23', '+', '23', ')']

exp = '((23**2)/23)'
print(tokenize(exp))
['(', '(', '23', '**', '2', ')', '/', '23', ')']

exp = '(23.34-(3*2))'
print(tokenize(exp))
['(', '23.34', '-', '(', '3', '*', '2', ')', ')']
```

Then you can perform a second pass and validate that the components are either an operator or a valid number as well as check that the expression is well formed with matching parentheses and alternating operator/operand.  At that point you will know exactly what part of the expression is incorrect.

for example:

```
def validate(exp):
    parts    = tokenize(exp)
    error    = ""
    pLevel   = 0
    previous = "$"
    for errorPos,part in enumerate(parts):
        pLevel += (part=="(")-(part==")")
        if pLevel<0: error="too many closing parentheses";break
        if part in "**+/)" and previous in "$**+-/(" :
            error = "missing operand";break 
        if part not in "**+-/)" and previous not in "$**+-/(":
            error = "missing operator";break
        previous = part
        if part in ["**","*","+","-","/","(",")"]: continue
        if all(p.isdigit() for p in part.split(".",1)): continue
        error = "invalid operand: " + part
        break
    if not error and pLevel!=0:
        errorPos,error = len(parts),"unbalanced parentheses"
    if not error and previous in "**+-/":
        errorPos,error = len(parts),"missing operand"
    if error:
        print("".join(parts))
        indent = " " * sum(map(len,parts[:errorPos]))
        print(indent+"^")
        print(indent+"|__ Error!",error)
```

...

```
validate('(( 200 + (4 * 3,14)) / ( 2 ** 3 ))')
                       
((200+(4*3,14))/(2**3))
         ^
         |__ Error! invalid operand: 3,14


validate('(( 200 + (4 * 3.14)) / ( 2 ** 3 )') 

((200+(4*3.14))/(2**3)
                      ^
                      |__ Error! unbalanced parentheses


validate('(( 200 + (4 * 3.14)))) / ( 2 ** 3 )') 

((200+(4*3.14))))/(2**3)
                ^
                |__ Error! too many closing parentheses


validate('(( 200 + *(4 * 3,14)) / ( 2 ** 3 ))')

((200+*(4*3,14))/(2**3))
      ^
      |__ Error! missing operand


validate('(( 200 + ()(4 * 3,14)) / ( 2 ** 3 ))')

((200+()(4*3,14))/(2**3))
       ^
       |__ Error! missing operand


validate('(( (200 + )(4 * 3,14)) / ( 2 ** 3 ))')

(((200+)(4*3,14))/(2**3))
       ^
       |__ Error! missing operand


validate('(( (200 + 2)(4 * 3,14)) / ( 2 ** 3 ))')

(((200+2)(4*3,14))/(2**3))
         ^
         |__ Error! missing operator
```

Comment: What your `parse` function does is called lexing or tokenization. In order to find out whether a given string is a valid expression or not, you still need to iterate over the array to check that each item is a valid number or operator, check that operators and numbers appear in the right places and that the parentheses are well-balanced.

Comment: @sepp2k, you are right, good catch.  I changed the name to avoid confusion.

Comment: @AlainT. wow! This is amazing! Thanks a lot! However, for the tokenization part, it will only split the positive numbers and it will treat negative numbers as '-' minus operator and digit. Is there a way whereby it can differentiate between negative numbers and '-' minus operator?

Comment: @wink, You would need to implement that on the parts after tokenization because the negation could apply to a parentheses group as well so it should be treated as high precedence operation rather than part of the numbers.  e.g. `13 * -(3**4)`.

Comment: @wink, from a validation perspective, you could check that operators are separated by operands and operands are separated by operators with the exception of the minus operator which can appear at the beginning or be preceded by another operator or an opening parentheses